Plugin JPA Buddy requires plugin 'com.intellij.jpa.jpb.model' to be installed
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and have installed the JPA Buddy plugin. However, the plugin is disabled and shows the following error message:

Requires plugin 'com.intellij.jpa.jpb.model' to be installed.

I've also searched for plugin 'com.intellij.jpa.jpb.model' in marketplace but didn't found it.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Please let me know if you need any additional information.


which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-242.23339.11

Hi! Please check if the Jakarta EE: JPA Model plugin is also installed in your IDE.

Check if the Jakarta EE: JPA Model plugin is installed
Plugin Homepage: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/24440-jakarta-ee-jpa-model
